# Get the category from permalink in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories

Sorry in advance if I ask a silly question. I just start to using Wordpress and would like to get the category from current permalink.

For example, the link is http://www.insight-post.tw/team-project/brexit/20160713/15654 and there is two categories "team-project" and "brexit" in it. I would like get the last category "brexit"

It not working in PHP with "get_the_category(permalink);"

Appreciated for the help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of categories for the post by using `wp_get_post_categories()`. Here's the link to the documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_categories/

Comment: I just want to get the last category from permalink instead of all of them. How should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`preg_match("/.*\/([a-z]*)\/.*\/.*", $permalink, $matches)`

The category "brexit" is in `$matches[0]`.

Note: the regular expression can be improved, but should do the job. See https://regex101.com/r/lY1gM4/1. I haven't tested the code yet, as I'm on a mobile device now.